# How to compare tensor inside tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My ultimate goal is to judge `placeholder` value.

Now I can judge a `placeholder` by using the regular python comparison expressions. Then, you know, it returns a tensor.

```
temp_tensor = a_placeholder > 0
```

Then for example , in `nn_ops.py`

```
temp1 = constant_op.constant(True)
temp2 = constant_op.constant(False)
```

how to compare `temp1` and `temp2`? Or whether `temp1` and `temp2` are equal.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compare"? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @sygi I want to judge the tensor value as the session run , so that I could fix a bug of tensorflow

Comment: @sygi  "compare" means equal or not .

Comment: What is wrong when you do `tf.equal` then?

Comment: @sygi `tf.equal` return a tensor. I need to compare tensor and `bool`

Comment: Why do you have these contraints? What exactly is the goal?

Comment: @sygi I want to return a empty tensor when the input over the contraints.

Answer (score 8):

Considering that `tf.equal(temp1, temp2)` returns tensor (e.g. `[[True], [False]]`) it is 
usefulless if you want to find an answer "is this tensor equal to another tensor", and you don't want compare elements.
What you might want is

```
if sess.run(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(temp1, temp2))):
    print('temp1 is equal temp2') 
else:
    print('temp1 is not equal temp2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

> tf.cond(tf.equal(temp1, temp2), true_fn, false_fn)

Where true_fn and false_fn are functions. 
For instance you could write something like

```
tf.cond(tf.equal(temp1, temp2)
       , lambda: print(temp1, ' and ', temp2 , 'are equal.')
       , lambda: print(temp1, ' and ', temp2, 'are NOT equal.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`tf.equal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#equal) function. Following the official docs, `tf.equal()` accepts two tensors and does the operation element wise. Something like this should work,

```
result = tf.equal(temp1, temp2)
```

Note, `result` will have the same dimension as `temp1` and `temp2` and filled with boolean values.

Comment: Thank you.But `tf.equal` return a tensor. I need to compare tensor and `bool`

Comment: One way out is to make the bool variable a placeholder. Then you can make multiple comparisons by passing it through sess

Comment: Did you get a satisfactory answer for this question?