# How to compare two strings in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, string, tensorflow

**Suppose I want to compare to element of a tensor of type string: text**

```
str = tf.constant(['0001', '0013', '0021', '0001'], dtype=tf.string)
str_1 = str[0]
str_2 = str[1]
if str_1==str_2:
    flag=True
else:
    flag=False
```

Comment: what is the problem actually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare tensor inside tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117586/how-to-compare-tensor-inside-tensorflow)

Comment: According to this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117586/how-to-compare-tensor-inside-tensorflow) tf.equal seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.math.equal()` to compare two string tensor.

code:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

str_var = tf.constant(['0001', '0010', '0020', '0001'], dtype=tf.string)
str_1 = str_var[0]
str_2 = str_var[1]
str_3 = str_var[3]

print(tf.math.equal(str_1, str_2).numpy())
print(tf.math.equal(str_1, str_3).numpy())
```

output:

```
False
True
```

Read more about `tf.math.equal()` from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/equal).

Comment: what is the difference between `tf.equal.math` and the operator `==`?