# Compare tensor element Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the equivalent operation in TF if I have x = [0, 10] and I want to do something like:

```
assert x[1] > x[0]
```

I tried the following:

```
    tf.debugging.assert_greater(x[1], x[0],
        message=f"{x[1]} has to be greater than {x[0]}"
    )
```

It didn't throw me any error when I have `x = tf.constant([10, 0])`
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare tensor inside tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117586/how-to-compare-tensor-inside-tensorflow)

Comment: I don't think so. I need to compare elements inside a tensor instead of comparing 2 tensors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't correctly understand `tf.debugging.assert_greater`. Take a look at the examples below. If `a > b`, it will do nothing but if `a < b`, it will throw an error, so its the other way around.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.debugging.assert_greater(0, 1,message=f"{x[1]} has to be greater than {x[0]}")

----
InvalidArgumentError: 0 has to be greater than 10
Condition x > y did not hold.
First 1 elements of x:
[0]
First 1 elements of y:
[1]
```

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.debugging.assert_greater(1, 0,message=f"{x[1]} has to be greater than {x[0]}")

----
nothing
```